# SOME Breakpoints not hitting in VS2012 / C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, breakpoints

I have somewhat a bizarre problem here. I have a **Solution** developed with VS2012 in C#. I have 6 **Projects** in the solution. My problem is, with some of the projects in the solution, no code change has any affect on Solution Build. It's not just new code, not even Breakpoints are getting hit!!

I have done a thorough research in the net, couldn't find anything helpful.

And of course, I have tried

- re-compiling
- deleting all the binaries and compiling again
- checked solution properties numerous times

etc...So, I think I have tried all the basics, but couldn't find a way out.

I gathered some screenshots, but I noticed I need at least 10 reps so I can't post them yet :(.

Any help at all will be greatly appreciated

Cihan Esen

**EDIT:** After the responses, I see that I have add, two other guys in my team is working on the same code, same build environment. They are not having this problem. I cross-checked every single configuration in their system which could remotely relate with this, we definitely have the same settings in VS.

And yes, I build the solution in DEBUG mode, not RELEASE.

I have tried seperate clean + build for the problematic projects -> no difference.

**EDIT 2**: I have to add; I have modified the code in the problematic project, so that I would see completely different output, but it didn't work. I mean that project/class of the solution, is still producing the same result, as if the code has not been changed at all. And yes, I have deleted all the binaries, saw them being built again.

This sounds **really stupid** to me but VS is acting as if it has a version of my source code of this problematic Project/Class, and it always compiles that version.

Comment: are you maybe compiling in release mode instead of debug mode?

Comment: Break the execution in Debug mode then check `Modules` window to see what assemblies are loaded

Comment: The solutions that you are having issues with, are they standalone project (aka can run on their own) or are they libraries? If the later, then check that you referenced them properly in the projects that you use them and not referencing an old version of a DLL

Comment: Could you be referencing the project dll's directly instead of referencing them as project references? That can cause this exact problem.

Comment: I know this is probably a stupid question, but it has to be asked. Are you sure that your breakpoints are supposed to get hit? Are they not in some if statement or something?

Comment: Yes my breakpoints should get hit. Those lines are executed, resulting, down the way, sending messages to some other modules, and I see the results.

Comment: Are you starting from IDE or are you attaching to a process for debugging? Is it the correct process your attaching to and is this process loading the correct dlls (or whatever) which you are expecting to be debugged?

And second question: Have you checked configuration manager under BUILD? Is your project marked to be build?

Comment: I am starting from the IDE and yes, all my sub projects are marked as BUILD in the configuration manager.

Comment: what kind of application are you developing? IIS can lock dll's, thus perform IIS reset.

Comment: and are you sure there are no post-build events which copy old dll's to your bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running in dubug mode and try this:

1. Go to your solution folder.
2. Show hidden files
3. Close your solution Delete **.sou** file for solution.
4. Add your break points, build your soltion and try.

Comment: Why? What does this mean? .sou is some user specific settings file, isn't it?

Comment: So I tried this, my breakpoint still not getting hit, but, this time IDE says 'your breakpoint will not get hit because the symbols were not loaded'. I never got this warning on any of my breakpoints before. BTW, same solution file is being used by two more persons here, and they don't have any problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

- throw away the obj and bin folders
- throw away your .suo files
- perform IIS reset for webapplications
- rebuild everything.

should do the trick :)